# Modularization of libraries

Tags: java

**User story:**
I'm developing a new program and try to put as much program logic into different libraries as possible to increase the reusability.

For interfaces where only a single library or "module" is needed, it is easy. Simply add the library to the project and work with the interface of the library.

**Problem:**
But now I want to outsource the processing layer, which I have to split in different libraries. Therefore I need to build an integration which supports such a structure.

I have looked into Java 9 but it seems it will not fit this use case.

How would a best practice for this use case look like?

Comment: “Therefore I need to build an integration which supports such a structure.” – could you please clarify what that means? Why can't you use these multiple libraries directly? Are you trying to bundle them into one library? Or do you want to expose a unified interface, like in the Facade Pattern?

Answer (score 7):

Don't make something reusable until you're **actually** trying to reuse it.

Some people like to architect their application in such a way that each piece can be "reused", without really defining what that reuse looks like.  The main point of reusability is to get as much mileage out of a preexisting component as you can.  If you're still designing your application, **you're not actually using anything at all**.

My advice would be to hold off on such discussions or thoughts until it's time to start splitting things out.  Duplicate code is a smell that you can leverage that lets you know when it'd be a good time to split your code up.

Comment: Maybe I should have explained this further in my question. 

The reason I write this new program is because I have three different programs which handle pretty similar use cases at the interfaces to other programs, e.g. Socket vs HTTP handler.  These applications have on the processing layer a totally different handling of incoming messages. Some would be hardcoded, performance oriented implementations and another one a xml defintion based scripted one with the target to allow the user to handle the edge cases themselves. 

But I definitely see your point here.